# Try to load CDN and invoke method in CDN js in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

In our App, we are using Video Publishing API (https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.js).

The problem with my test case is, we are externally invoking a method "Connect(-,-)" in openttok.js.

But how we can achieve through JMeter to Test Video Publishing?

I tried with following way,

```
Test Plan
   Thread Group
       Http Request
          call cdn: https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.js
          Post Request:
                JSR223 PostProcessor: use variable in CDN JS
                      //OT varible is available in OpenTok JS.
                      var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionID);
```

These are the Screens:

Http Request for OpenTok.js
[image]

Post Processor:
[image]

But it throws an error

> Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: ReferenceError: "OT" is not defined

I think, OpenTok not loading or not available to Post Processor Script.

How can I load OpenTok and use a variable within this Js?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it this way as [JMeter is not a browser and cannot execute JavaScript](http://jmeter.apache.org/).

I would recommend the following approach

1. Download [Opentok Server jar](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Java-SDK/releases)
2. Obtain all the dependencies, for OpenTok Server 3.0.0 they would be

   ```
   async-http-client-1.9.40.jar
   commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar
   commons-digester-1.8.1.jar
   commons-lang-2.6.jar
   commons-logging-1.2.jar
   commons-validator-1.6.jar
   jackson-annotations-2.9.0.pr4.jar
   jackson-core-2.9.0.pr4.jar
   jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr4.jar
   jose4j-0.5.1.jar
   netty-3.10.6.Final.jar
   ```
3. Put all the .jars under [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
4. Restart JMeter to pick the jars pu
5. Add JSR223 Sampler to your Test Plan
6. Use the following code to create a session:

   ```
   import com.opentok.OpenTok

   def apiKey = 123456789
   def apiSecret = 'your_api_secret'

   OpenTok opentok = new OpenTok(apiKey,apiSecret)
   def session = opentok.createSession()
   ```

References:

- [OpenTok Java SDK Usage](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Java-SDK#usage)
- [OpenTok Documentation](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/java/reference/index.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Dmitri, tried but throwing exception  `om.opentok.exception.RequestException: Could not create an OpenTok Session. The server response was invalid. response code: 403
 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158) ~[groovy-all-2.4.10.jar:2.4.10]
 at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]`.         check logs at 
  https://www.pastiebin.com/5966007852128

Comment: It looks like `async-http-client-1.9.40.jar` versioning issue. Tried 1.6 also. But the same issue raised.  REF: https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Java-SDK/issues/79

Comment: Found SDK functions are wrong. We can create session directly like `def session = new Session("test session", apiKey, apiSecret);`. And now I'm able to create Session ID and Token. But if we need to publish video, it's not possible by Server SDK. We should use client js. I consult OpenTok team for any Rest API call for joining the session. But they informed there is no way to joining session except client js.

Comment: I debug Joining session in Browser, client js sends API call with Session id along with Request Header with some parameters. I guess those are by token id related. Somehow, the token is manipulated in client js and sends as Request Header.